# How to mark duplicate values in another column MySQL

Tags: mysql

I reviewed this forum but could not find correct answer. I am looking for best way to find duplicate values in one column and to mark them in another column.

So if there are two the same order IDs (they contain different suffixes: E - for electricity and G - for Gas) then I need flag 'Dual Fuel'. However, if the order ID appears only once then I need flag 'Single'.

I have these data example:

[image]

I tried to remove suffixes E and G from the Order ID to get proper duplicate values, then to use this method:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT Order_ID,
          left(Order_ID, length(Order_ID)-1) AS EX
   FROM my_table
   ORDER BY left(Order_ID, length(Order_ID)-1) DESC) d1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT Order_ID,
          left(Order_ID, length(Order_ID)-1) AS EXS,
          COUNT(left(Order_ID, length(Order_ID)-1)) AS external_count
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY left(Order_ID, length(Order_ID)-1)
   HAVING COUNT(left(Order_ID, length(Order_ID)-1)) > 1) d2 ON d2.Order_ID= d1.Order_ID
```

Thanks to that I would get Order ID and the count of occurances in next column. IF > 1 then Dual Fuel, IF less then Single.

But this seems not to work and it is messy, is there any simpliest way to acheive something like this?

Thanks,
Pawel

Comment: *I have these data example:* Provide sample data as formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO textual scripts, not as a picture.

Comment: Does the value in 2nd source column matches the suffix in 1st column strictly? Does the value in 1st column is 9 chars strictly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark duplicated values MySQL without using GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977262/mark-duplicated-values-mysql-without-using-group-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` in a `CASE` expression:

```
select orderid,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from tablename 
      where left(orderid, length(orderid) - 1) = left(t.orderid, length(t.orderid) - 1))
      and right(orderid, 1) <> right(t.orderid, 1) 
    )  then 'Dual Fuel'
    else 'Single' 
  end result
from tablename t
```

If the `id`s have a fixed length of 9 chars then the code can be simplified:

```
select orderid,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from tablename 
      where left(orderid, 8) = left(t.orderid, 8)
      and right(orderid, 1) <> right(t.orderid, 1) 
    )  then 'Dual Fuel'
    else 'Single' 
  end result
from tablename t
```

Comment: Hi, first query seems to work, second one does not as the id length is not fixed. First solution gives me 99% correct answers.. there is some number of affected occurrences where I have two the same order ids (after I remove suffix E and G) and it is still marked as Single. But anyway, thank you for help.

Comment: @Pawel_L the conditions: `left(orderid, length(orderid) - 1) = left(t.orderid, length(t.orderid) - 1)) and right(orderid, 1) <> right(t.orderid, 1)` guarantee that if after the last char is removed the 2 ids are equal and the last chars are not equal then the row will be marked as 'Dual Fuel'. So the problem is not with the code. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is - some order IDs where broken (old entry), they had wrong suffix. When I exclude wrong IDs I get 100% correct result. It worked, thank you very much. Pawel